# How to add child's name attribute to parent

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm a newb, and I'm experimenting with creating custom radio boxes where the parents receive their children's name and selected value attributes, then removes the name attribute from the parent's children.

```
$(".radio").parent().addClass("radio-buttons"); //add styling
$(".radio").parent().attr("name", $(this).next().attr("name")); // supposed to assign names to parents

$(".radio").removeAttr("name"); //remove name after assignment to parent



$(".radio").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("a").css({
        background:"",  
        "box-shadow": ""
        }); //reset any previous selections

    $(this).parent().attr("value", $(this).attr("value")); //assign parent the selected value

    $(this).css({
        background:"#005fc3",
        "box-shadow": "2px 3px 5px #004793 inset"
    }); // Styling for selected state

});
```

I am stuck at trying to get the parents to receive their children's name attribute.
This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Jdpsv/

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there a link beetween up radios and down radios ?  When they talk about parents and children, they talk about nested elements in the document. Your lists of radios are in separated divs. There is no link beetween them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a `value` attribute to a `div`, instead you can use `data-value`

```
$(this).parent().data("value", $(this).attr("value"));
```

Or any other moniker you wish, as long as the HTML markup is `data-moniker` and you access via `.data('moniker')`